# Безопасная авторизация

Tags: php, авторизация

Пишу авторизацию на php, но я не знаю насколько она безопасна.

Принцип работы:

1. POST данные отправляются на сервер.
2. Проверяются логин и пароль.
3. Если есть такой пользователь, добавляем его в бд ( ID пользователя, первые 3 цифры IP адреса ).
4. Сохраняем ID авторизации в сессию.
5. Авторизация пройдена успешно, но это не все.
6. Каждую минуту меняется значения AuthID ( ID авторизации ).

Вот скажите насколько такой принцип БЕЗОПАСЕН?

Хакер же за 1 минуту не сможет же перехватить значения AuthID, и сменить их?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хакер может за несколько миллисекунд перехватить.

Используйте принцип двойного замка. Для этого подойдет почти любое надежное шифрование.

Отправитель на посылку(внутри - логин, пароль) вешает свой замок(то есть, шифрует ее).
Получатель молча шифрует ее повторно уже своим ключом и отправляет обратно.
Отправитель расшифровывает свой шифр и опять шлет серверу.
Сервер открывает свой шифр и получает логин и пароль.
Итог: ни логин ни пароль не засветились. При любой попытке вклиниться, письмо не откроется на какой-то стороне.

Естественно, шифрование должно быть надежным.

Comment: а чем лучше шифровать? md5? sha1?

Comment: шифровать лучше RSA, AES:) Если вы используете md5, расшифровать вы уже не сможете. =/ Ну, за приличное время. Тем более, sha1.

Кстати, я вам соврал: ассиметричное шифрование при такой схеме необязательно.

Comment: А как отправитель должен зашифровать так, чтоб это осталось незамеченным, и чтоб алгоритм не светить?

Comment: Криптостойкость алгоритмов основана на незнании ключа, а не на незнании алгоритма. Поэтому пусть светит - пожалуйста. не зная ключа, хакер не сможет взломать посылку за достаточно короткое время.

Заметте, даже сервер не знает ключа, которым было зашифровано сообщение. Ему это не надо: он шифрует и расшифровывает только своим ключом.

1) отправитель вешает замок1 на сундук. (сундук+замок1)
2) сервер вешает замок2 на сундук (сундук+замок1+замок2). он на этом этапе НЕ открывает его.
3) отправитель снимает замок1. (сундук+замок2)
4) сервер снимает замок2. (сундук)

Comment: Суть вопроса не меняется: как сделать так, чтоб не засветить ключ?

Comment: > А как отправитель должен зашифровать так, чтоб это осталось незамеченным, и чтоб алгоритм не светить?
Я шифрую POST запросы.

Comment: >>@Bars says: как сделать так, чтоб не засветить ключ?

Не светить ключ.   

Ключ клиента находится ТОЛЬКО у клиента. Он его не пересылает. Просто придумывает и никому не говорит.

Ключ сервера нахордится только у сервера. Он его тоже придумывает и не пересылает, и никому не говорит. Все операции с ключами происходят только там, где эти ключи созданы.

Пересылается только логин и пароль. НО. они зашифрованы тем самым ключом, который мы никому не говорим.

Comment: Ребят, а не подскажете, ведь просто использовать $_SESSION['username'] не надёжно? ещё надо что-то при авторизации сделать?

Comment: Толсто, очень толсто. =/

Если все-таки не троллинг: для некоторых нужд вашу конструкцию с успехом можно использовать. например, просто для отслеживания перемещения человека по сайту. Там, где не стоит задачи разделения прав владения.

Comment: Может кинете ссылку на скачку AES? Ищу в гугле, но не могу найти :(

Comment: @knes спустя 5 лет ваш вопрос еще актуальный! Я хотел поинтересоваться. Если клиент шифрует данные своим ключем, а сервер своим, то как они расшифруют данные друг друга? Если данные не расшифровываются относительно ключа отправителя, а только относительно своего ключа тогда мы можем вообще не трогать реальные данные, хакер может использовать зашифрованные данные и отправлять их на сервер будто он знает ключ. Я верно понял?

Answer (score 0):

> 3 цыфри

цифры

> Проверяется логин и пароль.

На что проверяется?

Что-то много лишних слов.
Проверили данные от пользователя по всем пунктам, отбросили лишние символы или выдали ему сообщение об ошибке.

Убедились еще раз в том что данные корректны.

Сделали запрос в БД, (да, нет) поглядели, если да, то куку ему, саму куку можно в БД записать(если есть огромное желание)

Почему каждую минуту у тебя меняется AuthID для чего?

> Вот скажите насколько такой принцип
> БЕЗОПАСЕН?

Может и безопасен, а уверен что других лазеек нет? Ну сделаешь ты крутую авторизацию, а он через другое место ломанет сайт и все.

Используй готовые решения в виде фреймворков, от многих геморных вопросов избавишься.